# Regular expression syntax

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a similar problem, to a previously asked question. But similar practices apparently do not produce similar results.

[Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165504/grouping-regex-in-ruby/6165653#6165653)

New question - I want to match the lines beginning in T as the first match, and the following lines beginning with X as the second match (as a whole string, to be later matched by another regex)

What I have so far is `(^T(\d+)\n(.*?)(?:the_problem)/m)` I don't know what to replace "the_problem" with, or even if that is the issue. I assumed some rendition `(?:\n|\z)`, but apparently not. Everything I tried, would not count the next occurrence of `^T(\d+)` as the start of a new group, and continue to capture all of the lines between each occurrence, at the same time.

```
Sample text;
T01C0.025
T02C0.035
T03C0.055
T04C0.150
T05C0.065
T06C0.075
%
G05
G90
T01
X011200Y004700
X011200Y009700
X018500Y011200
X013500Y-011200
X023800Y019500
T02
X034800Y017800
X-033800Y-017800
X032800Y017800
T03
X036730Y003000
X038700Y003000
X040668Y-003000
X059230Y003000
T04
X110580Y017800
X023800Y027300
X095500Y028500
X005500Y-006500
X021500Y-006500
T05
X003950Y002000
X003950Y004500
X003950Y007000
T06
X026300Y027300
M30
```

I only want to capture the shorter version of T01, T02,...T0n, not the longer version at the top, then the entire collection of `^X(-?\d+)Y(-?\d+)` that follows it, as another match.

```
Result 1.
Match 1. T01
Match 2. X011200Y004700
         X011200Y009700
         X018500Y011200
         X013500Y-011200
         X023800Y019500

Result 2.         
Match 1. T02
Match 2. X034800Y017800
         X-033800Y-017800
         X032800Y017800

Result 3.         
Match 1. T03
Match 2. X036730Y003000
         X038700Y003000

         ....etc....
```

Thanks in advance for any help ;-) Note: I prefer to use raw Ruby, without extensions or plugins. My version of ruby is 1.8.6.

Comment: At a glance, it looks like you should really just write a small, line-by-line parser instead of trying to cram everything into a regex.

Comment: That may happen in the future, but I'm using a few different files to obtain information, and regular expression have not failed me yet - neither have the wonderful folks on here ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
^(T[^\s]+)[\n\r\s]((?:(?:X\S+)[\n\r\s])+)
```

It makes the groups for the `X` lines into non-capturing groups, then puts all the repetitions of the final pattern into a single group. All the X lines will be in a single capture.

You can test this using Rubular (an indispensable tool for developing regular expressions) http://rubular.com/r/PRnurKy64Q

Comment: Very nice job indeed - thank you for the explanation as well!

Comment: I noticed that it works in Rubular, with or without the multi-line flag, do you know the significance of that? btw... I never close my Rubular tab ;-)

Comment: I believe the multiline flag is used to let some of the built-in character classes (I believe it's `\s` that it affects) match a newline. Since you're matching newline explicitly, it doesn't matter whether you use the flag.

Comment: I see - thank you. I got the full working code up and running, just got to get the receiving app to handle the information. Thanks again! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

this seems to work...

```
^(T[^\s]+)[\n\r\s]((X[^\s]+)[\n\r\s]){1,}
```

Comment: Almost - it stops at the second line containing X, in each group. And each of those is a unique match...

Comment: hrm.. it works here http://www.rubular.com/r/sI5tzQm4TB ..what is the line of code you're using?

Comment: I followed the link, you used `^(T[^\s]+)[\n\r\s]((X[^\s]+)[\n\r\s]){0,}` this time, but the same results... only 2 X matches and they're unique, they need to be one match.

Comment: Just FYI, did you know that `\S` is equivalent to `[^\s]`, and `+` is equivalent to `{1,}`?

Comment: @David, I'm clicking on the link you provided.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure I understand your problem, but I'll give this a shot. It looks like you want:

```
/(^T\d+$(^X[-A-Z\d]+$)+)*/g
```

This will have to be run under multiline mode so that ^ and $ match after and before newlines. Word of caution: I don't have much practice with mulitline regex, so you might want to do a sanity check on the use of ^ and $.

Also, I notice you didn't include the lines similar to `T01C0.025` in your sample results, so I made the `T\d+` assumption based on that.

Comment: I couldn't get that to work, I'm evaluating my regex in Rubular, and it has no `/g` option. The lines like `T01C0.025...` are not meant to be captured.